# Which Java language mechanisms allow code reuse and minimize ripple effects?

Tags: java

The questions asks:

Recount all of the java lenguage mechanisms that

(a) Facilitate code reuse, and

(b) Minimize ripple effects due to requirements
changes.

I am not sure if I am understanding this correctly. For (a) I thought it would be Composition, Association and Inheritance, and for (b) I thought it would be Encapsulation and Polymorphism; but I'm not sure if this is what the question asks and I am not sure if I am missing another mechanism. Also I am not sure about what the question mean by "Java language mechanisms" ?

Can someone help me to clarify this, my book really does not do a good job of explaining this.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, composition and association aren't Java language mechanisms, they're related to OOP as a concept.
But Interfaces, Abstract classes and Generics are.

Regarding ripple effect, I would go with this definition:
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=123

Constants, private fields (Encapsulation) and again Interfaces/Abstract classes (Polymorphism).

Answer (score 1):

A) Methods, Classes and Inheritance. These are the pure language mechanisms. I wouldn't say composition and association are real mechanisms, they are concepts of oop in general and not associated with the java language.

B) Named Constants instead of magic numbers, minimizing visibility. There is no real polymorphism in java as there is in c++ for example. But using Interfaces as references is a really good idea, as the implementations are easily replaceable. It also allows you to make your code more configurable using the factory pattern or even Dependency Injection. This problem and the advantages of using interfaces is well explained in [this article.](http://www.journaldev.com/2394/java-dependency-injection-design-pattern-example-tutorial)
Again, polymorphism and encapsulation are oop concepts and not associated directly with the java language.